# Impossible to create interface field when copy an object

Tags: c#, interface, clone, field

given this class definition:

```
  public class Frame
    {
        IFrameStream CapturedFrom;
    }
```

I want implement Clone() method in this class, but problem is:

How to create the IFrameStream field in the destination instance? - I just don't know its implementation, how to create the instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the semantics. In other words, what does the `CapturedFrom` field mean?

From your code, I assume that it would make sense to set the `CapturedFrom` field of the new instance in the `Clone()` method to the same value as the `CapturedFrom` field of the source instance. This is what's usually known as a "shallow copy".

Alternatively, you can leave it null. After all, the new instance hasn't been captured from a stream but cloned anew.